# Celery TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python, dictionary, rabbitmq, celery, site-packages

I'm trying to run celery, and can't run it because of the following exception:

```
[2023-02-14 11:25:11,689: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: TypeError("unhashable type: 'dict'")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shira/PycharmProjects/demo/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 203, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/Users/shira/PycharmProjects/demo/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/Users/shira/PycharmProjects/demo/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 365, in start
    return self.obj.start()
  File "/Users/shira/PycharmProjects/demo/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 332, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "/Users/shira/PycharmProjects/demo/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/Users/shira/PycharmProjects/demo/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 628, in start
    c.loop(*c.loop_args())
  File "/Users/shira/PycharmProjects/demo/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/loops.py", line 94, in asynloop
    update_qos()
  File "/Users/shira/PycharmProjects/demo/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/common.py", line 435, in update
    return self.set(self.value)
  File "/Users/shira/PycharmProjects/demo/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/common.py", line 428, in set
    self.callback(prefetch_count=new_value)
  File "/Users/shira/PycharmProjects/demo/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/tasks.py", line 43, in set_prefetch_count
    return c.task_consumer.qos(
  File "/Users/shira/PycharmProjects/demo/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 558, in qos
    return self.channel.basic_qos(prefetch_size,
  File "/Users/shira/PycharmProjects/demo/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/channel.py", line 1894, in basic_qos
    return self.send_method(
  File "/Users/shira/PycharmProjects/demo/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 79, in send_method
    return self.wait(wait, returns_tuple=returns_tuple)
  File "/Users/shira/PycharmProjects/demo/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 99, in wait
    self.connection.drain_events(timeout=timeout)
  File "/Users/shira/PycharmProjects/demo/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 525, in drain_events
    while not self.blocking_read(timeout):
  File "/Users/shira/PycharmProjects/demo/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 531, in blocking_read
    return self.on_inbound_frame(frame)
  File "/Users/shira/PycharmProjects/demo/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/method_framing.py", line 77, in on_frame
    callback(channel, msg.frame_method, msg.frame_args, msg)
  File "/Users/shira/PycharmProjects/demo/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 537, in on_inbound_method
    return self.channels[channel_id].dispatch_method(
  File "/Users/shira/PycharmProjects/demo/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 156, in dispatch_method
    listener(*args)
  File "/Users/shira/PycharmProjects/demo/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/channel.py", line 1629, in _on_basic_deliver
    fun(msg)
  File "/Users/shira/PycharmProjects/demo/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 626, in _receive_callback
    return on_m(message) if on_m else self.receive(decoded, message)
  File "/Users/shira/PycharmProjects/demo/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 591, in on_task_received
    strategy = strategies[type_]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

I tried to uninstall celery, stop rabbitMQ process, and googled it and didn't find any solution.

I run a simple basic code of celery using only one function ("add", without any dictionary).
I think maybe there is some issues with the libraries I import.

Answer (score 0):

I put a breakpoint where the exception is thrown.
I found out that I sent the illegal task a few days ago, so I understood I need to remove it from the queue so other tasks could be done.

I used this command:
celery -A tasks purge

This solved me the issue :)